# How do you deal with decimal (,) and javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, decimal

I've an `ASP.NET MVC` application, `C#`, and some numbers into my `Model` in `decimal` type, which treat the fractional part as comma (i.e. 12,5).

I serialize them and send to the client using `JSON`, which correctly convert the comma to point:

```
var result = Json(new { Value = myModel.myValue }); // become Value = 12.5
```

Than I process the data client side, with some math function, getting the number value always with point (i.e. 12.5 * 3 = 37.5).

But, when I need to post back to the server the processed value, if I keep the point and I store the value into my `Model` (which is `decimal`, as said), it truncate the values after the point.

Do I really need to do `result.replace('.', ',')` before sending back data client side? Damn not so good. Best practices?

The paradox is that for mvc's jquery validator (being `decimal` required) I need to print the value into the input box with comma. The round-trip is crazy...

Comment: "which treat the fractional part as comma"  sounds like a localisation problem.

Comment: Its not a localization problem :) In Europe, its the comma that separate the fractional part. Its correct, I want it so!

Comment: "Its not a localization problem"    "In Europe"      I'm in the UK. Good luck!

Comment: @Davesoft: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg I'm in Italy, it seems correct, isn't?

Comment: "Do I really need to do result.replace('.', ',') before sending back data client side?"   Sounds like a localisation problem...

Comment: Always send data in neutral culture and date in [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringify` - This converts a JavaScript object into a string,

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(Yourvalue);
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve trouble client side. Once I need to operate math with JS, I still need the `.`, so the twofold conversion seems needed in any case :O

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful, rather than burdening the server with the client's wild choice of encoding, get the javascript to do it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

It nicely turns 98.76 into 98,76 when passing it through 'it-IT'